# Dynamic property key

Tags: freemarker

My project has several events and I store event IDs in Site Properties and as each event page extends the same core template I want to assign the specific event ID to a generic variable.

The issue is that when I try to insert a variable inside the property key reference freemarker returns syntax errors. Is there any way around this?

```
${sectionName}
//rootSection

<@property key="eventID-rootsection" /> 
//32465

<#assign eventID = <@property key="eventID-${sectionName}" /> >
//syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `property` is defined as a directive (maybe as a macro), and not as a method (or function). You need a method (or function) version of it. Then your example would look like:

```
${sectionName}
//rootSection

${property("eventID-rootsection")}
//32465

<#assign eventID = property("eventID-${sectionName}")>
```

To define `property` as such, either implement `TemplateMethodModelEx` or use the `#function` directive.

Comment: BTW, functionality like this is often better solved by implementing `TemplateHashModel`, and then you can write `properties.somePropertyName`. Well, you have a `-` there... then it's `properties.eventID\-rootsection`. Yeah, that `-` had to be escaped... kind of ruins it aesthetically. (: The 2nd case with the dynamic key would be `properties['eventID-${sectionName}']` then.